# Add indicator variable to long data frame for when the value increases from one year to the next

Tags: r, plyr

I have a long data frame with three columns `fyear`, `tic`, and `dcvt` (for fiscal year, ticker, and total convertible debt). There are about 18 fiscal years and a few thousand tickers. I would like to add an indicator variable that is one whenever `dcvt` goes up from one year to the next.

I tried `ddply`, but I lost the `fyear` column and wasn't sure how to get it back.

```
library(plyr)
temp <- data.frame(fyear = rep(1992:2009, 10), tic = rep(letters[1:10], each = 18), dcvt = rnorm(180, 200, 10))
my.fun <- function(x) x <- c(0, ifelse(tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1) > 0, 1, 0))
temp2 <- ddply(temp, "tic", colwise(my.fun, "dcvt"))
```

I also tried to cast to wide with the `reshape2` package, then run `for` loops, but of course, that took forever.

Is there a way that I can do this quickly? Should I make a wide `zoo` object then use `diff`? I would like to avoid passing through a time series, if I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using tranform in ddply sometimes help us greatly:

```
ddply(temp, .(tic), transform, dcvt=c(0, diff(dcvt)>0))
```

Comment: Thanks! Rookie mistake; I'd had even seen that `transform` inside `ddply` trick on here a few months back!

Answer (score 2):

`ddpy()` handles a data set of this size (10^2) quite well. However, for larger datasets and for situations where you don't necessarily need to return a full dataframe, I would consider the following `do.call` + `lapply` solution:

```
my.fun <- function(cur.tic){
  as.numeric(diff(temp$dcvt[temp$tic == cur.tic]) > 0)
}

do.call("c", lapply(unique(temp$tic), my.fun))
```

To demonstrate the performance payoffs (unfairly given the vector vs. dataframe issue), I took the OP's sample data, created new data frames of magnitude 10^4, 10^5, and 10^6, and then ran `system.time()` on @kohske's `ddply` solution and the solution above:

Original data (10^2):

```
> system.time(do.call("c", lapply(unique(temp$tic), my.fun)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.003 
> system.time(ddply(temp, .(tic), transform, dcvt=c(0, diff(dcvt)>0)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.020   0.000   0.013
```

10^4 sample data

```
> system.time(do.call("c", lapply(unique(temp.2$tic), my.fun)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.002 
> system.time(ddply(temp.2, .(tic), transform, dcvt=c(0, diff(dcvt)>0)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.040   0.000   0.036
```

10^5 sample data

```
> system.time(do.call("c", lapply(unique(temp.3$tic), my.fun)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.004 
> system.time(ddply(temp.3, .(tic), transform, dcvt=c(0, diff(dcvt)>0)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.270   0.000   0.279
```

10^6 sample data

```
> system.time(do.call("c", lapply(unique(temp.4$tic), my.fun)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.010   0.000   0.018 
> system.time(ddply(temp.4, .(tic), transform, dcvt=c(0, diff(dcvt)>0)))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.110   0.070   6.186
```

Not a gripe about `ddply()` - rather, just an effort to share some code that I found useful while working on a very similar issue with a much larget dataset recently.

Comment: Not really a fair comparison given that ddply returns a data frame and your function returns a vector. ave would probably be even faster

Comment: +1 that's a great point, @hadley. I didn't mean my comment as a gripe about `ddply` so much as an elaboration of an approach that I had found to be very efficient with a pretty large dataset (10^7) that I was working on recently. Editing my answer to clarify this point!